# Buscar una celda en un rango de celdas de otra hoja, y retornar la celda de al lado en excel

Tags: excel, busqueda

Tengo 2 hojas:
-**clientes**
-**buscar**

En **clientes** tengo los datos de los clientes, son varios datos pero solo necesito estos campos:
[image: Hoja con todos los datos a buscar]

y en la hoja **buscar** tengo una celda donde ingreso el **RUT** a buscar

Ejemplo:

[image: Buscador]

Cómo logro que en otras 2 celdas en la hoja **buscar** aparezca el **RUT** y **NOMBRE** si es que escribo un **RUT** y encontró coincidencia en toda la columna **RUT** de la hoja **clientes**?

Logre hacerlo con esta formula que busca en el rango de toda la columna RUT, pero cómo logro que me retorne el RUT donde hubo coincidencia y el nombre del lado?

```
=SI(O('clientes'!A2:A11=buscar!A2);RUT donde encontro la coincidencia ('clientes'!A2);"No se encuentra")

=SI(O('clientes'!A2:A11=buscar!A2);nombre donde encontro la coincidencia ('clientes'!B2);"No se encuentra")
```

lo que busco es que yo al escribir 19 *(A2,B2 en la hoja clientes)*, aparezca lo siguiente en la hoja de **buscar**.

No puedo hacerlo directamente en la hoja clientes ya que se van añadiendo datos
[image: hoja buscar]

O si escribo 27 retorne RUT A3 y nombre B3 en otra función.

Comment: La función [Función BUSCARV](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-buscarv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) hace exactamente lo que pides. Hay millones de ejemplos en Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la celda **B2** de la hoja **BUSCAR** puedes utilizar esta fórmula:

```
=BUSCARV(A2;CLIENTES!A:B;2;0)
```

La cual busca la primera coincidencia del RUT que digites en la celda **A2**, y trae el nombre del cliente a la celda **B2**.

Si no encuentra coincidencias o la celda **A2** de la hoja **BUSCAR** está vacía, te devuelve un **#N/A**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto, me ha servido, ¿y si es que quiero usar mas celdas aparte de la A2?, tipo A3,A4, etc. ¿tendria que poner ese rango dentro de la funcion BUSCARV?

Comment: Es correcto, si necesitas buscar información de otra columna, cambias el rango de columnas y le indicas el número de columna que quieres obtener. Por ejemplo, si tienes en la columna **D** el **APELLIDO**, entonces la fórmula quedaría así: `=BUSCARV(A2;CLIENTES!A:D;4;0)`

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion y edicion